# ASP.NET 5.0 build issue on TFS build server 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I recently added a test project to an ASP.NET 5.0 project. The tfs build server is unable to find assemblies for my test project. project.json file below

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConfigTests test project",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-build3109",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-build134",
    "Moq": "4.2.1507.118",
    "ConfigSvc": "3.0.0-*",
    "FluentAssertions": "3.5.0"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

The build outputs errors as such.

```
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency xunit 2.1.0-beta4-build3109
Unable to resolve dependency xunit.runner.dnx 2.1.0-beta4-build134
Unable to resolve dependency Moq 4.2.1507.118
Unable to resolve dependency FluentAssertions 3.5.0
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging 1.0.0-beta6
Unable to resolve dependency Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1
Using Assembly dependency framework/fx/mscorlib 4.0.0.0
  Source: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll
Using Assembly dependency framework/fx/System 4.0.0.0
  Source: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll
Using Assembly dependency framework/fx/System.Core 4.0.0.0
  Source: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll
Using Assembly dependency framework/fx/Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0.0
```

The build command is as follows:

> C:\Users\build.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5\bin\dnx.exe --appbase "C:\Builds\2\A\CI_Config\src\Config\ConfigSvc\ConfigSvcTests" "C:\Users\build.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5\bin\lib\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.dll" pack "C:\Builds\2\A\CI_Config\src\Config\ConfigSvc\ConfigSvcTests" --configuration Release --out "C:\Builds\2\A\CI_Config\bin"

my project doesnt reference most of these assemblies. I'm curious as to where the tfs build agent is looking for the assemblies. Maybe I am missing something crucial here about dependencies with the project.json file

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/) by david fowler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With regard to the dependencies, those mostly look like dependencies
   of Microsoft . AspNet . Mvc which is in your dependency list. As I
   understand it you only reference the top level dependencies in your
   project.json and the lower level dependencies are worked out. I think that is what you are seeing. InVS 2015 you can drill down on
   the dependencies.
2. To the error: I have not tested it but it seems likely you are running into issues because you are referencing beta6 but are using beta5 dnx in your
   build command.

Some useful links:

1. http://jameschambers.com/2015/07/asp-net-5-beta-6-is-in-the-wild/
2. http://www.joshgraham.com/upgrading-from-asp-net-beta-5-to-beta-6/
3. http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/